# part file empty while running pig in Eclipse using libraries

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I ran a sample pig script in mapreduce mode and it ran successfully.

My pigscript:

```
allsales = load 'sales' as (name,price,country);
bigsales = filter allsales by price >999;
sortedbigsales = order bigsales by price desc;
store sortedbigsales into 'topsales';
```

Now, I am trying to implement that in eclipse (currently I am running using libraries).

**One doubt**: Pig Local mode means that we need hadoop installation as default?

IdLocal.java:

```
public class IdLocal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
     PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
     runIdQuery(pigServer, "/home/sreeveni/myfiles/pig/data/sales");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
  public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) 
                      throws IOException {

  pigServer.registerQuery("allsales = load '" + inputFile+ "' as (name,price,country);");
  pigServer.registerQuery("bigsales = filter allsales by price >999;");
  pigServer.registerQuery("sortedbigsales = order bigsales by price desc;");
  pigServer.store("sortedbigsales","/home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/topsalesjava");
  }
}
```

The console is showing success for me, but my part file is empty.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

1) local mode pig does not mean that you have to have hadoop installed.  you can run it without hadoop and hdfs.  Everything will be performed single threaded on your machine and it should read/write from your local filesystem by default.

2) Regarding your empty output, ensure that your input file exists on your local filesystem and that it has records in the 'price' field greater than 999.  You could be filtering them all out otherwise.  Also, pig defaults to tab separated files.  Is your inputFile tab separated?  if not, then your schema definition will have the 'name' field hold the entire row in the file, and 'price' and 'country' will always be null.

hope that helps